# Left Click in File Browser (fe Open Dialoge) or Outliner not working

Tags: mouse

I had a strange expierience this morning. When I started blender I tried to open a file. Most strangely enough I couldn't click a file or a folder anymore or anything inside the file/folder part of the window. 
Same is true for the Outliner: I wanted to rename some files but I just couldn't interact with them. I had to use right click / rename. Or for selecting object in the outliner I had to use right click / select. 
Apart from that every left click works as it should. 
I tested several other mice - all have the same result.
Please note that this issue is blender only. I can click everything in any other program.

Another thing that started at the same time was the behaviour of the menu bar. When 2 instances of blender were running and I hovered over the opened windows they immediately collapsed again instead of showing me selectable previews.
This is system wide though... I have no idea what the cause might be.

To make it more clear I am talking about this part of the outliner: 
[image: outliner]

and this part of the file explorer:
[image]

Comment: Which OS? Has there been a recent update,?

Comment: Windows and no  :)
Blender is 2.79
I also have linux installed. There everything is perfectly fine.